# Optimal way to generate sequential id Java

Tags: java, java-stream, generator

I would like to generate custom ID like this :

```
Test0000001
Test0000002
Test0000010
Test0000011
Test0000100
Test0000101
```

But my method always append and generate with `000000` (0000001, 00000010, 00000011) instead i would like to generate ids like mentioned above

```
public String generateId(int nextId) {
    return "Test" + String.format("%06d%s", 0, nextId);
}
```

Guide me on optimal way to generate ID. Thanks

Comment: Try simplyfy your format string like that: (...) return "Test" + String.format("%06d",nextId);

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 20).mapToObj(i -> "Test" + String.format("%6s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(" ", "0")).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Thanks for the answer , I think you are converting it to BinaryString, instead i want it like this : 
Test0000001
Test0000002
Test0000003
Test0000004
.....
....
Test0000010
Test0000011
Test0000012
.....
...
Test0000100
Test0000101

Comment: You said something completely different. Adjust the code as you need.

Comment: @Grzesl or even simpler, `return String.format("Test%06d",nextId);`